# curl -L equivalent command in wget?

Tags: curl, wget

I'm trying to switch this `curl` command to `wget` because `curl` is posing some vulnerability to the system.

```
curl -fsSL https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/v${TINI_VERSION}/tini-static-amd64
```

What is `wget` parameter equivalent to `curl -L`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

There is no such parameter, as `wget` follows redirects by default.

Example:

```
% wget --verbose https://google.com --output-document=/dev/null
--2022-12-06 15:40:20--  https://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 216.58.220.110
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|216.58.220.110|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://www.google.com/ [following]
--2022-12-06 15:40:20--  https://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 142.251.42.164
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|142.251.42.164|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘/dev/null’

/dev/null                                     [ <=>                                                                                ]  14.82K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2022-12-06 15:40:20 (49.4 MB/s) - ‘/dev/null’ saved [15179]
```

You can *disable* following redirects by setting `--max-redirect` to 0:

```
% wget --verbose https://google.com --output-document=/dev/null --max-redirect=0
--2022-12-06 15:41:00--  https://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 216.58.220.110
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|216.58.220.110|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://www.google.com/ [following]
0 redirections exceeded.
```

So these are roughly equivalent in terms of following redirects:

| Wget | curl |
| --- | --- |
| `wget` | `curl -L` |
| `wget --max-redirect=0` | `curl` |